# How can I use CONCAT with AVG and ROUND?

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I am trying to find the round average of bike trip and I want to change it from INTEGER to STRING64 and divide by /60 in order to get the result in minutes.

I was trying

SELECT
ROUND(AVE(CONCAT(bike_trip, STRING64)/60))

It looks like something is missing to me.

Comment: Why do you think you can use a string in an arithmetic operation such as division? Why do you want to convert it from an integer to a string anyway?

Comment: First point - CONCAT (or CONCATENATE) is for joining multiple values together, not for converting from one data type to another.  Second point - I don't think you should have to try and do any explicit conversion, Google Sheets will take care of the conversion for you.  However, if your underlying problem is that you've maybe been ended up with only a whole number as your result, but you'd like a decimal result, then I'd suggest dividing by 60.000, and you may then get an implicit conversion to a decimal data type, which will ultimately impact the data type of the result value

Comment: Post few sample data and then show your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `bike_trips` is a range name in google sheets, try this:

```
=TEXT(AVERAGE(bike_trips) / 60.0, "0.00") & " minutes"
```

or

```
=ROUND(AVERAGE(bike_trips) / 60.0, 2) & " minutes"
```

I'm not sure why you want a string as the result, but I'm also unsure what "string64" is meant to be.

If however this is a SQL related question you need to identify the underlying database as syntax can vary. However this is likely to work as  most of the functions involved are common across several dbs:

```
select ROUND(AVG(bike_trips) / 60.0, 2) || ' minutes' from some_table
```

or:

```
select CONCAT((ROUND(AVG(bike_trips) / 60.0, 2),' minutes') from some_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(AVG(100.00 / 60),2) AS NVARCHAR) AS _average
-- String64 is not a function use Nvarchar instead.
-- and you have to give precision for Round Function.
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!!